# ElasticSearch: Reverse Geo Bounding Box Query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, geospatial

ES newbie here.

I have an index of users with `boundaries` eg  `north, south, east, west`. These boundaries are where they are willing to work. I also have their home address `lat, lng` and the `radius` of the circle that gives me the bounds.

I then want to search a given `lat, lng` and get results based on users that are prepared to travel to this location. EG, with their `bounds`.

Reading the docs, I can't see if this is currently possible. From my understanding I will need to do two searches (Or one search then filter).

• First do a `geo_distance` search with say 100miles from my `lat, lng`

• Then filter these results with a `geo_bounding_box` to see they fall into params.

It doesn't seem like a great way to go. Is there a better option? It is worth noting that a lot of these documents are new and I can easily reformat if needed.

Any suggestions on the right way to go about this?

Is there a filter I can use to see if my `lat, lng` are with the bounds?

Thanks in advance for your help. Cheers.